# Youtube data api return dailyLimitExceededUnreg reach

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the YouTube Data API to get the YouTube channel information, it was working before two days now it is giving me below error:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
}
```

Is there any new update on YouTube Data API?
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not an issue, the message is very clear. Your unauthenticated use has exceeded the daily quota. Either authenticate or limit your daily use.

Comment: I am a new developer of the youtube-data-api  , so please guide me how to authenticate  . Thanks in advance

Comment: follow the official guide [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: @Erevald I searched a lot for the way to authenticate but count not find , I also  verified the domain . And also added the key restriction but still not working  . Can any one help in giving me the way to authenticate

Comment: As additional information, you can also check the [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) that shows Youtube Data API supports OAuth 2.0 to access private data. Don't forget that the account to be used should be linked to Youtube account. You could also use the [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) that lets you estimate the quota cost for an API query. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

In order to access any Google API you need to identify your application.   This rule has not been enforced on all Google APIs.  If you say your request has worked in the past I suspect that they have begun to enforce this now with the YouTube API.

The problem is that you have either not authenticate your application using Oauth2 or you are not sending an API key along with this request.

1. You need a Google Account to access the Google Developers Console, request an API key, and register your application.
2. Create a project in the Google Developers Console and obtain authorization credentials so your application can submit API requests.
3. After creating your project, make sure the YouTube Data API is one of the services that your application is registered to use:
   a. Go to the Developers Console and select the project that you just registered.
   b. Open the API Library in the Google Developers Console. If prompted, select a project or create a new one. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.
4. If your application will use any API methods that require user authorization, read the authentication guide to learn how to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization.

see [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: @DalmTo  I followed the above all steps but still getting the same error . please suggest me any other way to understand and come-out from it.

Comment: Did you add the key to your request?  I sugest you post some code we can not help you more without seeing your code.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error. The mistake I was making is not setting the API Key value while requesting. Please set the API Key attribute.

If you are using youtube data v3 api use following code snippet.

`playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setKey(YOUR_API_KEY_VALUE);`

If you are using the Html request, then use following format :

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=8&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`