# Javascript Youtube Data API v3 : Inserting video in a playlist (Video not found)

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to add a video to my private playlist on youtube when I submit the form.
I request the id of the selected video, which also prints correctly in my console.
But when I try to add the video to the playlist, I get a 404 error : Video not found.However, if open up the error I get the following message...

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

This is my code to add the video to the playlist.

```
        $('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var id = $("#idArticle").val();

             var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
                part: 'snippet',
                resource: {
                  snippet: {
                    playlistId: 'PLcQyg31odPUkASkMF09QBGqD8qKOQoe-l',
                    resourceId: {
                        videoId: id,
                        kind: "youtube#video",
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
              request.execute(function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                $('#videoDetails').html('<p>' + response + '</p>');
              });
             console.log("Added.?");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111143/5832311), this problem may occur if you have either not authenticate your application using Oauth2 or you are not sending an API key along with this request.

> 1. You need a Google Account to access the Google Developers Console, request an API key, and register your application.
> 2. Create a project in the Google Developers Console and obtain authorization credentials so your application can submit API requests.
> 3. After creating your project, make sure the YouTube Data API is one of the services that your application is registered to use:
>      a. Go to the Developers Console and select the project that you just registered.
>      b. Open the API Library in the Google Developers Console. If prompted, select a project or create a new one. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.
> 4. If your application will use any API methods that require user authorization, read the authentication guide to learn how to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization.
>
> see [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: All these are implemented in de application. Now i'm getting a different error while I didn't change any code.